# Does not rerender in <h:selectOneMenu>

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have two combobox(category and subcategory), i want to render subcategory combobox that is depending on the selection id of category combobox. But, subcategory combobox doesn't render? 
Here is my code,

```
<h:panelGrid>
    <h:outputText value="Cateogyr : "/>
    <rich:comboBox defaultLabel="Enter some value" >
      <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="subCombo" ajaxSingle="true"/>
      <f:selectItems value="#{bookManager.categoryList}" />
    </rich:comboBox>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:panelGrid>
    <h:outputText value="Sub Category : "/>
    <rich:comboBox defaultLabel="Enter some value" id="subCombo">
       <f:selectItems value="#{bookManager.subCategoryList}" />
    </rich:comboBox>  
    </h:panelGrid>
```

I printed out in backing bean where the subcategory combobox is rendered, but it does not appear.
Please, if u have any idea, let me know.

Comment: Do you want to rerender the subcategory combo box when the value of category combo box is changed?

Comment: yes. But the subcategory combo box does not rerender.Sorry, I've left out my code. Here is two combo box,

Comment: Your code works fine in my environment after wrapping both of the `panelGrid`s with a `<h:form>` component.

Comment: I've already added <h:form>, but i can't it to render. And how did u do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're working with JSF 1.2 and RichFaces. By the posted code, it looks like you need to do some fixes in your actual code:

- You're missing the `<h:form>` that wraps the data to be sent to the server. Your code should be like this:

  ```html
  <h:form>
      <h:panelGrid>
          <h:outputText value="Category : "/>
          <rich:comboBox defaultLabel="Enter some value" >
            <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="subCombo" ajaxSingle="true"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{bookManager.categoryList}" />
          </rich:comboBox>
      <!-- rest of JSF/HTML code... -->
  </h:form>
  ```
- In order to work properly, your `bookManager` managed bean needs to have Session Scope or Request scope and the `@KeepAlive` annotation in order to work without problems. For performance hits, I would recommend using Request scopes. Your class should look like this

  ```
  @KeepAlive
  public class BookManager {
      //class code...
  }
  ```

Seeing your code, it looks like you're retrieving the `bookManager.subCategoryList` on the getter of your bean (from database or cached resource). Make sure your managed bean getters and setters are pretty straight forward (like `public int getNumber() { return this.number; }`) and **do not contain any business logic code** in it because JSF could call the getter methods more than once. For further info about this, see:

- [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2090033/1065197).

Now, how to solve this problem of retrieving the subcategory list when changing a value in the `<rich:combobox>`? Use the `action` component attribute of `<a4j:support>` invoking a method that retrieves and prepare the data in the `bookManager.categoryList`.

JSF Code

```html
<a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="subCombo" ajaxSingle="true"
    action="#{bookManager.obtainSubcategoryList}" limitToList="true" />
```

Java Code

```
@KeepAlive
public class BookManager {
    public void obtainSubcategoryList() {
        //retrieve the data in this action.
        this.subCategoryList = ...;
    }
    //class code...
}
```

Comment: By the way, seeing your question edit, I assume you forgot to post the bind to the value of the `<rich:comboBox>`, in other words, the `<rich:comboBox value="#{bookManager.someProperty}">`.

Comment: Than u for your comments, but it doesn't rendered. :(

Comment: @MyoThuZarKyaw what problem now you have?

Comment: I've already do all of you said. But, obtainSubcategoryList() does not work after selecting the categoryList. It didn't rerender.

Comment: Have you tested that the `obtainSubcategoryList` is being invoked? Is there any JSF message about this issue (you can write an `<h:messages>` section for this)?

Comment: Yes, I have put messagees tag. The combo box doesn't still rendered. :( Nothing happen.

Comment: @MyoThuZarKyaw did you check the `obtainSubcategoryList` is executed (maybe put a break point or a `System.out.println("entered obtainSubcategoryList method");` to make sure). Also, did you bind the value of the `<rich:combobox>` to a value of your managed bean? As a last resource, try replacing `<h:selectOneMenu>` instead of `<rich:combobox>` (for both comboboxes in your page).

Comment: Yey.. Now, it works. I replace with <h:selectOneMenu> instead of <rich:combobox>. But I have still want to know a little. I gave list item as List<SelectItem> array to combo box. Coz i want itemvalue and itemlabel. In <rich:combobox> it is ok. But in <h:selectOneMenu> , it only show id.

Comment: @MyoThuZarKyaw read here: [`<h:selectOneMenu>` wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)